# Angular2 : Chain http requests with concat()

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-http, angular2-observables

I have some difficulties to chain several HTTP requests.

First, the request is defined in this service method that returns a cold Observable.

**FormPartService**

```
submitFormPart(id: string, part: string, data: any) {

    let body = JSON.stringify({
        claimFileId: claimFileId,
        part: part,
        data: data
    });

    return this.http.post('/form-part', body)
                    .map( (res) => { 
                            let body = res.json();
                            if (body.data){
                                return body.data;
                            }
                        } 
                    );
}
```

I have a variable number of form part to submit depending if they are dirty or not, so I iterate over an array filled with these forms. Each call is not dependant of the return of the previous call, what I need in the end is only what is returned after the **last call**

To do this, I tried the `concat()` operator that seems to me more adapted to my case than `switchMap()`. Here's my attempt :

**Component**

```
var formToSubmit = [...]; // Contains dirty forms that be sent to the backend
var id = '123';
var stream$; // Will contain the first Observable

formToSubmit.forEach((form, index) => {
    if (index === 0) {
        // Set stream$ with the first Observable
        stream$ = this.formPartService.submitFormPart(id, form.getPartName(), form.getValues())
    }
    else {
        // Concat the first Observable with the others
        let obs$ = this.formPartService.submitFormPart(id, form.getPartName(), form.getValues());
        stream$.concat( obs$ );
    }
});

stream$.subscribe((globalForm) => {
    console.log(globalForm);
})
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. When I debug step by step, everything goes well, I have `stream$` set with an Observer, the `stream$.concat()` doesn't break. But what I get in network is **only the first request**, not the chained.

What I'm doing wrong ? 
Thanks a lot

**edit**
I replaced my code with the example Kwintep provided me to optimize the request chaining. Unfortunately, the requests are well executed one by one, but once it gets done I have the following error `unknown type returned` :

```
core.umd.js?e2a5:3462 EXCEPTION: unknown type returnedErrorHandler.handleError @ core.umd.js?e2a5:3462next @ core.umd.js?e2a5:6924schedulerFn @ core.umd.js?e2a5:6172SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ VM1077851:223SafeSubscriber.next @ VM1077851:172Subscriber._next @ VM1077851:125Subscriber.next @ VM1077851:89Subject.next @ VM1077847:55EventEmitter.emit @ core.umd.js?e2a5:6164onError @ core.umd.js?e2a5:6388onHandleError @ core.umd.js?e2a5:6263ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js?fad3:207Zone.runTask @ zone.js?fad3:139ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js?fad3:304
core.umd.js?e2a5:3467 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.umd.js?e2a5:3467next @ core.umd.js?e2a5:6924schedulerFn @ core.umd.js?e2a5:6172SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ VM1077851:223SafeSubscriber.next @ VM1077851:172Subscriber._next @ VM1077851:125Subscriber.next @ VM1077851:89Subject.next @ VM1077847:55EventEmitter.emit @ core.umd.js?e2a5:6164onError @ core.umd.js?e2a5:6388onHandleError @ core.umd.js?e2a5:6263ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js?fad3:207Zone.runTask @ zone.js?fad3:139ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js?fad3:304
core.umd.js?e2a5:3468 TypeError: unknown type returned
    at Object.subscribeToResult (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:297:2), <anonymous>:69:27)
    at CombineLatestSubscriber._complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:797:2), <anonymous>:108:46)
    at CombineLatestSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:131:2), <anonymous>:114:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyComplete (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:430:2), <anonymous>:155:30)
    at InnerSubscriber._complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:315:2), <anonymous>:30:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:131:2), <anonymous>:114:18)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:131:2), <anonymous>:132:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:131:2), <anonymous>:114:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:261:2), <anonymous>:1499:42)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:236:37)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:101:2), <anonymous>:6233:41)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:235:42)
    at Zone.runTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:136:47)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:304:33)
  -------------   Elapsed: 336 ms; At: Mon Nov 14 2016 13:58:04 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)   -------------  
    at Object.onScheduleTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2666:2), <anonymous>:76:18)
    at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:213:49)
    at Zone.scheduleEventTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:156:39)
    at zoneAwareAddListener (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:773:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest.addEventListener (eval at createNamedFn (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2)), <anonymous>:3:43)
    at Observable.eval [as _subscribe] (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:261:2), <anonymous>:1540:22)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:113:2), <anonymous>:56:27)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:113:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:273:2), <anonymous>:54:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:113:2), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Object.subscribeToResult (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:297:2), <anonymous>:21:27)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:430:2), <anonymous>:120:38)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:430:2), <anonymous>:117:14)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:430:2), <anonymous>:100:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyComplete (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:430:2), <anonymous>:152:18)
    at InnerSubscriber._complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:315:2), <anonymous>:30:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:131:2), <anonymous>:114:18)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:131:2), <anonymous>:132:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:131:2), <anonymous>:114:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:261:2), <anonymous>:1499:42)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:236:37)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:101:2), <anonymous>:6233:41)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:235:42)
    at Zone.runTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:136:47)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:304:33)
  -------------   Elapsed: 861 ms; At: Mon Nov 14 2016 13:58:03 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)   -------------  
    at Object.onScheduleTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2666:2), <anonymous>:76:18)
    at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:213:49)
    at Zone.scheduleEventTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:156:39)
    at zoneAwareAddListener (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:773:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest.addEventListener (eval at createNamedFn (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2)), <anonymous>:3:43)
    at Observable.eval [as _subscribe] (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:261:2), <anonymous>:1540:22)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:113:2), <anonymous>:56:27)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:113:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:273:2), <anonymous>:54:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:113:2), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Object.subscribeToResult (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:297:2), <anonymous>:21:27)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:430:2), <anonymous>:120:38)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:430:2), <anonymous>:117:14)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:430:2), <anonymous>:100:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:131:2), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at ArrayObservable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:370:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at ArrayObservable.Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:113:2), <anonymous>:56:27)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:113:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MergeMapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:430:2), <anonymous>:75:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:113:2), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:113:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at CombineLatestOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:797:2), <anonymous>:74:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:113:2), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at EditorComponent.submitAll (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/app.js:1220:2), <anonymous>:81:18)
    at _View_EditorComponent0._handle_click_52_0 (EditorComponent.ngfactory.js:602:28)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:101:2), <anonymous>:9698:28)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:209:2), <anonymous>:1877:40)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:209:2), <anonymous>:1990:115)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:203:28)
    at Object.onInvoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:101:2), <anonymous>:6242:41)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:202:34)
    at Zone.runGuarded (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:110:47)
    at NgZoneImpl.runInnerGuarded (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:101:2), <anonymous>:6271:82)
    at NgZone.runGuarded (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:101:2), <anonymous>:6504:77)
    at HTMLButtonElement.outsideHandler (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:209:2), <anonymous>:1990:83)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:236:37)
    at Zone.runTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:136:47)
    at HTMLButtonElement.ZoneTask.invoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:304:33)ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.umd.js?e2a5:3468next @ core.umd.js?e2a5:6924schedulerFn @ core.umd.js?e2a5:6172SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ VM1077851:223SafeSubscriber.next @ VM1077851:172Subscriber._next @ VM1077851:125Subscriber.next @ VM1077851:89Subject.next @ VM1077847:55EventEmitter.emit @ core.umd.js?e2a5:6164onError @ core.umd.js?e2a5:6388onHandleError @ core.umd.js?e2a5:6263ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js?fad3:207Zone.runTask @ zone.js?fad3:139ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js?fad3:304
VM1077851:227 Uncaught TypeError: unknown type returned(…)
```

Comment: Do you want these calls to be done one after the other or can they be done in parallel?

Comment: Hi, I absolutely need them to be done one after the other :)

Comment: concat() **returns** a new observable. It doesn't mutate the original one. `stream$ = stream$.concat( obs$ );`.

Comment: True @JBNizet. The overal code however can be rewritten easily in something better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code can be optimised to this:

```
// Mocks an http call that takes 1 second to complete
function fakeRequest(id) {
  console.log('doing the request for id ' + id);
  return Rx.Observable.of(id).delay(1000);
}

let items = ["1", "2", "3"];

// create an observable from the array that emits every item one after one
Rx.Observable.from(items)
   // use concatMap, this operator accepts a function that returns an observable.
   // It will subscribe to this observable and not take on any next values
   // untill that observable completes.
   // So it will get '1' and perform the request. As soon as this one completes
   // it will handle the next value, which will be '2' and so on.
  .concatMap(
    (val) => {
      return fakeRequest(val)
   })
   // Use combine all to make sure the subscription below isn't call untill
   // every element in the original array is handled.
  .combineAll()
   // Get back an array with the results from every call, just take the last one
   // if you really need it
  .subscribe((val) => console.log(val));
```

Comments inline. Jsbin example here: http://jsbin.com/hequvokaya/edit?js,console

Comment: Nice, this example seems pretty clear :). Thanks a lot the explanations, I'll adapt it to my code. Do I need to import any rxJs operators manually ? I already have an `import 'rxjs'`, it guess it loads it all. Edit : from where can I import `Rx` ? ^^

Comment: If you have an import for 'rxjs/rx' you'll get everything normally (ps: don't forget to accept my answer :)).

Comment: Ok I found : `import * as Rx from 'rxjs'` in my component. I'm not familiar with all these imports, but if I already have an `import 'rxjs'` in my vendor.ts, won't it double the loading ?

Comment: Even though Http requests are well performed, I have an error "Unknown type returned" :/

Comment: Can you post the entire stacktrace?

Comment: @Kwintep, I posted an edit with the stacktrace. Hope it will be readable

Comment: Hmm, I don't immediately see what could be wrong. Is it possible to extract a jsbin example where you can reproduce the error? The rxjs part should be correct.

Comment: @Kwintep, it works if I include the raw code you gave into my component, including the `fakeRequest()` function. So there's something wrong with my environment values. In my `concatMap()` function, I directly make a `return this.formPartService.submitFormPart(id, form.getPartName(), form.getValues())`, it supposed to return a cold Observable. The problem seems to come from this portion.

Comment: In my concatMap(), I just tried a `return Rx.Observable.of(this.formPartService.submitFormPart(id, form.getPartName(), form.getValues());` (so return an Observable of Observable ?) there is no error anymore, I have in the end an array with the results from every call. But every calls are performed in the same time. Otherwise, it seems to mean that what is returned from my `formPartService.submitFormPart()` is not expected. Does Http.post().map() returns a expected type ?

Comment: @DlafCreative Hmm I'm starting to loose overview of the question. Is it possible to create a new question with the current problem. That would help a lot I guess. You also have more chance someone will find an answer on a new question (if I'm unable to).

Comment: yes, I created a new question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40598352/cant-use-concatmap-with-angular2-http

Answer (score 1):

`concat()` **returns** a new observable. It doesn't mutate the original one.

You want

```
stream$ = stream$.concat(obs$);
```

Comment: True, but overal the code can be rewritten much more clear, check my answer below

Comment: It was that :) thank you. Also, I notice that the callback of the subscribe() is executed as many times as I concatened Observables. Is there a way I can make it execute only after the last request ?

Comment: Check my answer and the Jsbin. It does exactly what you want.