# Can't use concatMap() with angular2 Http

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-http, angular2-observables

I need to chain many http requests, the number of request is variable and they are not dependant from the result of the previous one, I just need to keep the returned object of the last request.

I've been given two solutions on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40533016/angular2-chain-http-requests-with-concat/40533856), the first solution using `Observable.concat()` works, but a contributor suggested me a more elegant way to perform that, by using `concatMap()`.

Here's my current code :

**MyComponent**

```
submitForms() {
    var formToSubmit = [...]; // Contains dirty forms that be sent to the backend (they are simple Angular2 Components)
    var id = '123';

    Rx.Observable.from(formToSubmit)
             .concatMap(
                  (form) => {
                      return this.formPartService.submitFormPart(id, form.getContext(), form.getValues());
                  }
              )
              .combineAll()
              .subscribe( (val) => {
                  console.log(val); // Should return an array of each value returned. I'll keep the last one. 
              } );
}
```

As you can see, I have an array with all dirty forms that need to be submitted to the backend.  I create an Observable from this array, then I use concatMap() to subscribe to the Observable of the passed function and wait for the result, before firing the next subscription.

Here's the `submitFormPart()` method from my **FormPartService**

```
submitFormPart(id: string, part: string, data: any) {

    let body = JSON.stringify({
        id: id,
        part: part,
        data: data
    });

    return this.http.post('/form-part', body)
                    .map( (res) => { 
                            let body = res.json();
                            if (body.data){
                                return body.data;
                            }
                        } 
                    );
}
```

It should simply return a simple cold Observable. Everything should work fine...

When I submit my forms, I have the error `unknown type returned`, the complete stacktrace :

```
core.umd.js?e2a5:3462 EXCEPTION: unknown type returnedErrorHandler.handleError @ core.umd.js?e2a5:3462next @ core.umd.js?e2a5:6924schedulerFn @ core.umd.js?e2a5:6172SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ VM1077851:223SafeSubscriber.next @ VM1077851:172Subscriber._next @ VM1077851:125Subscriber.next @ VM1077851:89Subject.next @ VM1077847:55EventEmitter.emit @ core.umd.js?e2a5:6164onError @ core.umd.js?e2a5:6388onHandleError @ core.umd.js?e2a5:6263ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js?fad3:207Zone.runTask @ zone.js?fad3:139ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js?fad3:304
core.umd.js?e2a5:3467 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.umd.js?e2a5:3467next @ core.umd.js?e2a5:6924schedulerFn @ core.umd.js?e2a5:6172SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ VM1077851:223SafeSubscriber.next @ VM1077851:172Subscriber._next @ VM1077851:125Subscriber.next @ VM1077851:89Subject.next @ VM1077847:55EventEmitter.emit @ core.umd.js?e2a5:6164onError @ core.umd.js?e2a5:6388onHandleError @ core.umd.js?e2a5:6263ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js?fad3:207Zone.runTask @ zone.js?fad3:139ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js?fad3:304
core.umd.js?e2a5:3468 TypeError: unknown type returned
    at Object.subscribeToResult (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:297:2), <anonymous>:69:27)
    at CombineLatestSubscriber._complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:797:2), <anonymous>:108:46)
    at CombineLatestSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:131:2), <anonymous>:114:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyComplete (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:430:2), <anonymous>:155:30)
    at InnerSubscriber._complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:315:2), <anonymous>:30:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:131:2), <anonymous>:114:18)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:131:2), <anonymous>:132:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:131:2), <anonymous>:114:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:261:2), <anonymous>:1499:42)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:236:37)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:101:2), <anonymous>:6233:41)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:235:42)
    at Zone.runTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:136:47)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:304:33)
  -------------   Elapsed: 336 ms; At: Mon Nov 14 2016 13:58:04 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)   -------------  
    at Object.onScheduleTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2666:2), <anonymous>:76:18)
    at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:213:49)
    at Zone.scheduleEventTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:156:39)
    at zoneAwareAddListener (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:773:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest.addEventListener (eval at createNamedFn (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2)), <anonymous>:3:43)
    at Observable.eval [as _subscribe] (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:261:2), <anonymous>:1540:22)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:113:2), <anonymous>:56:27)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:113:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:273:2), <anonymous>:54:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:113:2), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Object.subscribeToResult (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:297:2), <anonymous>:21:27)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:430:2), <anonymous>:120:38)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:430:2), <anonymous>:117:14)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:430:2), <anonymous>:100:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyComplete (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:430:2), <anonymous>:152:18)
    at InnerSubscriber._complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:315:2), <anonymous>:30:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:131:2), <anonymous>:114:18)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:131:2), <anonymous>:132:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:131:2), <anonymous>:114:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:261:2), <anonymous>:1499:42)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:236:37)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:101:2), <anonymous>:6233:41)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:235:42)
    at Zone.runTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:136:47)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:304:33)
  -------------   Elapsed: 861 ms; At: Mon Nov 14 2016 13:58:03 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)   -------------  
    at Object.onScheduleTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2666:2), <anonymous>:76:18)
    at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:213:49)
    at Zone.scheduleEventTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:156:39)
    at zoneAwareAddListener (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:773:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest.addEventListener (eval at createNamedFn (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2)), <anonymous>:3:43)
    at Observable.eval [as _subscribe] (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:261:2), <anonymous>:1540:22)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:113:2), <anonymous>:56:27)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:113:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:273:2), <anonymous>:54:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:113:2), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Object.subscribeToResult (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:297:2), <anonymous>:21:27)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:430:2), <anonymous>:120:38)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:430:2), <anonymous>:117:14)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:430:2), <anonymous>:100:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:131:2), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at ArrayObservable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:370:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at ArrayObservable.Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:113:2), <anonymous>:56:27)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:113:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MergeMapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:430:2), <anonymous>:75:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:113:2), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:113:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at CombineLatestOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:797:2), <anonymous>:74:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:113:2), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at EditorComponent.submitAll (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/app.js:1220:2), <anonymous>:81:18)
    at _View_EditorComponent0._handle_click_52_0 (EditorComponent.ngfactory.js:602:28)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:101:2), <anonymous>:9698:28)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:209:2), <anonymous>:1877:40)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:209:2), <anonymous>:1990:115)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:203:28)
    at Object.onInvoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:101:2), <anonymous>:6242:41)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:202:34)
    at Zone.runGuarded (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:110:47)
    at NgZoneImpl.runInnerGuarded (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:101:2), <anonymous>:6271:82)
    at NgZone.runGuarded (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:101:2), <anonymous>:6504:77)
    at HTMLButtonElement.outsideHandler (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/vendor.js:209:2), <anonymous>:1990:83)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:236:37)
    at Zone.runTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:136:47)
    at HTMLButtonElement.ZoneTask.invoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:7777/polyfills.js:2660:2), <anonymous>:304:33)ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.umd.js?e2a5:3468next @ core.umd.js?e2a5:6924schedulerFn @ core.umd.js?e2a5:6172SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ VM1077851:223SafeSubscriber.next @ VM1077851:172Subscriber._next @ VM1077851:125Subscriber.next @ VM1077851:89Subject.next @ VM1077847:55EventEmitter.emit @ core.umd.js?e2a5:6164onError @ core.umd.js?e2a5:6388onHandleError @ core.umd.js?e2a5:6263ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js?fad3:207Zone.runTask @ zone.js?fad3:139ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js?fad3:304
VM1077851:227 Uncaught TypeError: unknown type returned(…)
```

I can't find where this error comes from. 
I tried the following, to test from the raw example I've been provided, and to debug in a certain way :

**MyComponent**

```
submitForms() {
    ...
    Rx.Observable.from(formToSubmit)
                 .concatMap(
                     (form) => {
                         return Rx.Observable.of(this.formPartService.submitFormPart(id, form.getPartName(), form.getValues());
                     }
...
}
```

Returning an Observable of an Observable... like this, the error disappear, the http calls are well executed, but they are executed at the same time in parallel.
That's not what I want, and that's certainly not viable of course, but it may just show that the problem comes from the return of my `submitFormPart()`, and so the return of `Http.post().map()` from Angular2 that `concatMap()` doesn't appreciate...

If it can be useful, here are my current versions :

```
"@angular/common": "2.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0",
"@angular/material": "^2.0.0-alpha.9-3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
"@angular/router": "3.0.0",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12"
```

I didn't try to upgrade these yet...

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you strip this only to necessary minimum? I have no idea where's the error thrown. Maybe this `Rx.Observable.from(formToSubmit)`? What's `formToSubmit`?

Comment: Hi, I did my best to strip the elements to the minimum. `formToSubmit` is a simple array, containing `@ViewChild` variables pointing to subcomponents that encapsulate angular forms. Like I said above, I use this array because the number of form to submit is variable and depends if they are dirty or not. I create an Observable from this array to process these forms one by one, like a contributor suggested me to do

Answer (score 0):

> I just need to keep the returned object of the last request.

Use `.takeLast(n)` to get the latest n observable, for your case, try changing your code to

```
Rx.Observable.from(formToSubmit)
   .concatMap(
       (form) => {
          return this.formPartService.submitFormPart(id, form.getContext(), form.getValues());
       }
   )
   .takeLast(1) // get only the latest observable 
   .subscribe( (val) => {
      console.log(val); // Now this should return the last emitted value
   });
```

Example [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/LTdGzf2nlFfPd2yrKg7p?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
Rx.Observable.zip(
  formToSubmit.map(form => this.formPartService.submitFormPart(id, form.getContext(), form.getValues()))
).subscribe(results => {
  let firstFormResult = results[0];
  let secondFormResult = result[1];
  ... etc. etc.
});
```

I do this whereever I have multiple independent requests... as soon as ALL requests are completed, Observable.zip will invoke your subscription.